# Which D&D 3.0 & 3.5 Dragonlance books are considered officially licensed third-party products?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, product-identification, books

[Hey I Can Chan's answer to the question "How do you tell if a D&D book is 3.0 or 3.5?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36990/47190) describes a category of products as follows (emphasis mine):

> officially licensed Dragonlance **third party** products—products bearing some combination of the Dungeons and Dragons logo and the Wizards of the Coast officially licensed product seal or including on their title pages that the product is officially licensed by Wizards of the Coast.

Which D&D 3.0 & 3.5 Dragonlance books are considered officially licensed third-party products?

Comment: @V2Blast I must know are you a professional editor, or am I just that sloppy. ;-) Regardless, thanks again!

Comment: Not a professional editor, unless someone wants to hire me :P Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dragonlance

[***Dragonlance Campaign Setting***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786930861) (Aug. 2003) was published by Wizards of the Coast; it is a first-party product and game-legal by default for any campaign that includes all official material—and includes the contentious feat Reserves of Strength (86 and see answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137399/8610) and see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/137410/8610) ). Other Dragonlance material bears the Wizards of the Coast seal but was published by [Sovereign Press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_Press,_Inc). The list below includes what the author considers significant releases germane to a readership looking to incorporate a wider variety of material into their games; it excludes purely narrative material like the various [*Tasselhoff's Map Pouch*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931567778) releases.

- 2003/11 *Age of Mortals*
- 2004/04 *Bestiary of Krynn*
- 2004/05 *Age of Mortals Campaign 1: The Key of Destiny*
- 2004/08 *Towers of High Sorcery*
- 2004/10 *War of the Lance*
- 2005/07 *Age of Mortals Campaign 2: Spectre of Sorrows*
- 2005/09 *Holy Order of the Stars*
- 2006/02 *Legends of the Twins*
- 2006/08 *Knightly Orders of Ansalon*
- 2006/09 *War of the Lance Campaign 1: Dragons of Autumn*
- 2006/11 *Age of Mortals Campaign 3: Price of Courage*
- 2007/04 *Bestiary of Krynn, Revised*
- 2007/08 *Races of Ansalon*
- 2007/09 *Dragons of Krynn*<sup>1</sup>
- 2007/11 *War of the Lance Campaign 2: Dragons of Winter*
- 2008/01 *War of the Lance Campaign 3: Dragons of Spring*

Dates, in some cases, are approximate. Also Web enhancements are available some of these texts; those can be found *via* Wayback Machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101123094805/http://dragonlance.com/products/enhancements/).

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Includes one of my favorite feats, the final iteration of the feat Mighty Steed (also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22mighty%20steed%22)). (It was also published in *Bestiary, Revised* and *Knightly Orders.*)

Comment: Years ago, when I found the Mighty Steed feat, it made some of my players very happy.